# Missing values in sentiment classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to build a sentiment analysis engine using python's sklearn package.
the problem is analyzing Rotten Tomatoes reviews on this Kaggle Competition

https://www.kaggle.com/c/sentiment-analysis-on-movie-reviews

the sentiments can take 5 possible values

I am using the following classifiers

1. Multinomial Naive Bayes
2. Logistic Regression
3. Stochastic Gradient Descent

Since these are all linear classifiers suited for binary classification, here are the steps that i have to take

1. Break up the training and test set into 5 parts, one part per sentiment.
   Lets say the possible values for the sentiment are a,b,c,d,e. So in part one of my data, i will have all the reviews, but the reviews that have sentiment 'a' will be marked as positive and all of the others will be marked as negative. Similarly i create other parts for the other sentiment values.
2. Clean up the data in all 5 parts
3. Create a pipeline and feed all the test set parts to my classifier, one after the other. I will store one result per part. So result of classifying part one is partOneRes and so on. Anything which is marked as positive in partOneRes belongs to sentiment 'a'. Similarly for other parts.
4. Finally i would like to combine the results for all 5 parts. I will look at partOneRes. Anything that is marked positive will be changed to Sentiment 'a'. I will do similarly for all the other parts. Then i simply merge the results.
5. It would have been ideal if i got no overlaps or duplicates. But i get a small number of duplicates, which is fine. I can add some logic to handle that.
6. I would do this for all three classifiers and finally i want to find out which classifier give me the best results.

My problem is that I can see that there are many reviews which my classifier was not able to put in any category! Why would this happen? Could it be due to the small size of the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restating, the problem is that the five binary models you've trained are not mutually exhaustive.  There are several possibilities.
First of all, do you have a 100% clean classification for each of the five sentiments, or are there some acknowledged classification errors?

You need a set that is mutually exclusive *and* exhaustive.  Your approach suggests, but hardly guarantees, this result.  You might consider an integrated solution that does make this guarantee.  Multi-class SVM is one such, but may not apply well to your situation.

If the classes are not 100% accurate, you can easily have all five rejecting a particular observation.  This suggests that your classification algorithms need tuning, or that the data themselves are not as amenable to classification as you would like.

You might also check that you've cleaned that data appropriately; a few errors can seriously move the class boundaries.

What I suspect is happening is a small-boundary effect: each class, when compared against the combination of the other four, "pulls in" its boundaries, leaving unclaimed territory between the final sets.

Do you have a way to check the classification parameters after training?  If so, can you visualize the five boundaries selected?  If you do find pathological gaps, are there training parameters you can tune, such as giving a larger epsilon to the training groups?

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions ! i will review my data and classifiers and try to figure out if i can tune it properly. i believe that i do not have too much training and test data so i guess i might have to live with the gaps. thanks for clarifying.